# Funcion js no suma la ultima fila de la columna

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una tabla que estoy alimentando con un JSON online, funciona bien, me trae mis datos sin problema.

Pero al intentar totalizar una columna, logro hacer la suma de la columna que deseo, pero siempre me falta que sume el valor de la última fila de abajo.

Espero que me puedan ayudar a hacer la modificación necesaria para que sume bien toda la columna.

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https: //milink/data2.json',
    success: function(response) {
        myArray1 = response
        buildTable1(myArray1)
        console.log(myArray1)
    }
})
                        
function buildTable1(data) {
    var table1 = document.getElementById('myTable1')
    table1.innerHTML = ''

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var row = `<tr>
            <td>${data[i].Codigo}</td>
            <td>${data[i].Vendedor}</td>
            <td>${data[i].Total.toFixed(2)} </td>
           
            </tr>`

        var table1 = document.getElementById('myTable1'), sumVal = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < table1.rows.length; i++) {
            sumVal = sumVal + parseFloat(table1.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML);
        }
        document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = "Total = " + sumVal;
        console.log(sumVal);

        table1.innerHTML += row
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Tienes que sacar el segundo `for` afuera del primero.

Comment: Si! Eso lo solucionó. Muchas gracias, lo dejo corregido por si le sirve a alguien.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias alanfcm .

Lo dejo corregido por si le sirve a alguien:

```
function buildTable1(data){
    
    var table1 = document.getElementById('myTable1')
                    
        table1.innerHTML = ''
                    
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            var row = `<tr>
                <td>${data[i].Codigo}</td>
                <td>${data[i].Vendedor}</td>
                <td>${data[i].Total.toFixed(2)} </td>
               
                </tr>`
    table1.innerHTML += row
       
    }
    var table1 = document.getElementById('myTable1'), sumVal = 0;
    
        for (var i = 0; i < table1.rows.length; i++)
        {
        sumVal = sumVal + parseFloat(table1.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML);
        }
        document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = "Total = " + sumVal;
        console.log(sumVal);
   
}
```